# Substitute a specific numeric sequence within a vector using R

Tags: r, replace, sequence

How can I identify a specific sequence in A (i.e. 1,1,0,0 and 0,0,1,1) and substitute these numbers with 1, 0.7, 0.3,0 and 0, 0.3, 0.7, 1, respectively (A2)?

In a nutshell transform this:

```
A<-c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
```

Into this:

```
A2<-c(1,1,1,0.7,0.3,0,0,0.3,0.7,1,1,1)
```

I have a long dataset so smooth it manually is not an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `slider` combined with `replace`:

```r
library(slider)

A <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)

replace.pattern <- function(x,pattern,replacement) {
  idx <- which(unlist(slide(x, .f=function(x) {identical(x,pattern)},.after = length(pattern)-1)))
  idx <- unlist(lapply(idx, function(i) i:(i+length(pattern)-1)))
  replace(x,idx,replacement)
}

A <- replace.pattern(A, c(1,1,0,0), c(1, 0.7, 0.3,0))
A <- replace.pattern(A, c(0,0,1,1), c(0, 0.3, 0.7, 1))

A
#>  [1] 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.7 0.3 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.7 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Thanks!